# Splitting large txt file into small ones based on specific content

Tags: c#, save, streamreader, delimiter, split

I got a large sequence of genome and I need to split it into small .txt files.

Sequence looks like this

```
>supercont1.1 of Geomyces destructans 20631-21
AGATTTTCTTAATAACTTGTTCAATGTGTGTTCAAATGATATGCCGTGATGTATGTAGCA
TAAACAGATGTAGTAGAAGAGTTTGCAGCAATCGTTGAGTAGTATTGCTTCTGTTGTTGG
>supercont1.2 of Geomyces destructans 20631-21
AGATTTTCTTAATAACTTGTTCAATGTGTGTTCAAATGATATGCCGTGATGTATGTAGCA
TAAACAGATGTAGTAGAAGAGTTTGCAGCAATCGTTGAGTAGTATTGCTTCTGTTGTTGG
TAAACAGATGTAGTAGAAGAGTTTGCAGCAATCGTTGAGTAGTATTGCTTCTGTTGTTGG
>supercont1.3 of Geomyces destructans 20631-21
AGATTTT (...)
```

And it should be splitted into small files with names: "1.1-Geomyces-destructans--20631-21", "1.2-Geomyces..." fulfilled with genome data.

My code after @JimMischel help looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace genom1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string filter = "Textové soubory|*.txt|Soubory FASTA|*.fasta|Všechny soubory|*.*";

        private void doit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bar.Value = 0;

            OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();

            // filter for choosing file types
            opf.Filter = filter;

            string lineo = "error"; // test

            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var lineCount = 0;
                using (var reader = File.OpenText(opf.FileName))
                {
                    while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
                    {
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                }

                bar.Maximum = lineCount;
                bar.Step = 1;

                FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

                fbd.Description = "Vyber složku, do které chceš rozdělit načtený soubor: \n\n" + opf.FileName; // dialog desc
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(opf.FileName))
                    {
                        bar.PerformStep();

                        if (line[0] == '>')
                        {
                           if (lines.Count >= 0)
                            {
                                // write contents of lines list to file

                                //quicker replace for better file name
                                StringBuilder prep = new StringBuilder(line);
                                prep.Replace(">supercont", "");
                                prep.Replace("of", "");
                                prep.Replace(" ", "-");
                                lineo = prep.ToString();

                                // append or writeall? how to writeall lines without append?
                                //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fbd.SelectedPath + "\\" + lineo + ".txt", lineo);
                                StreamWriter SW;
                                SW = File.AppendText(fbd.SelectedPath + "\\" + lineo + ".txt");

                                foreach (string s in lines)
                                    {
                                        SW.WriteLine(s);
                                    }

                                SW.Close();

                                // and clear the list.
                                lines.Clear();
                            }
                        }
                        lines.Add(line);
                    }
                    // here, do the last part
                    if (lines.Count >= 0)
                    {
                        // write contents of lines list to file.

                        /* starts being little buggy here...

                        StreamWriter SW;
                        SW = File.AppendText(fbd.SelectedPath + "\\" + lineo + ".txt");
                        foreach (string s in lines)
                        {
                            SW.WriteLine(s);
                        }
                        SW.Close();

                        */
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is large enough to fit into memory, you can call `File.ReadAllText` to get it into a string. Then you go through and extract text between `>` characters. Something like:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText("filename");
int pos = s.IndexOf('>');
while (pos != -1)
{
    int newpos = s.IndexOf('>', pos+1);
    string text = s.Substring(pos+1, newpos - pos);
    // now write text to a file

    // update current position
    pos = newpos;
}
// here you'll have to handle the last part of the file specially.
```

I assume you can figure out how to name the files correctly.

If you can't fit the entire file into memory, then you can read the file character-by-character or do some kind of buffering. The problem is easier if you know that the `>` is always at the start of a line. Then you can write:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("filename"))
{
    if (line[0] == '>')
    {
        if (lines.Count > 0)
        {
            // write contents of lines list to file.
            // and clear the list.
            lines.Clear();
        }
    }
    lines.Add(line);
}
// here, do the last part
if (lines.Count > 0)
{
    // write contents of lines list to file.
}
```

Comment: This is amazing response! Your comment really helped me!


But still I got one question (I'm sorry) - I'm little confused about that two IFs - why should be the last part here?

I made some changes to my code. Could you please look it up with your experienced eye?


There's a problem with generating txt files, where ">supercont1.1" have content from ">supercont1.2" etc.


PS: Is it better to use WriteAllText or AppendText? Which one is quicker? I'm asking becouse this program will be reading really big files

Comment: You don't want `lines.Count >= 0`, but rather `lines.Count > 0`. No need to create the file if there are no lines. The reason for the "last part" is that the file probably doesn't end with a ">" on the line (or maybe it does). If it doesn't, then you'll have the last part of the file buffered in the `lines` list, and you need to output it. `File.AppendText` is fine. If this program is working with very large files, you're going to be limited by the speed of the disk, so any small optimization you can make in the logic isn't going to make much difference.

Comment: @user1337432: You probably don't want to use `line` to extract the file name. Instead, use `lines[0]`, which is the marker for the beginning. That's why I have the `lines.Count > 0` there. And also why I have the "last part." If you use `line`, your labeling will be off.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Problem was with "lines[0]" :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the easiest way is to first read the entire file using [File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx).  Then just use [String.Split(">")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) which will return an array of what I assume would be your new files contents.